# Nslog timestamp

Tags: iphone, timestamp, nslog

I want to nslog the device motion timestamp property .

The device motion is in the class CMMotionManager.devicemotion.timestamp

Any ideas.

Comment: what do you mean by timestamp?

Comment: the CMMotionManager.devicemotion is of type CMDeviceMotion, and that class doesn't contain property for timestamp ?

Comment: @Robin -- It inherits `timestamp` from CMLogItem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Edit**: Please see Nicolas Lauquin's answer. Per the comments, the following solution is **not correct** but is retained here for history (and because I can't delete it since it is currently marked accepted).

---

The `timestamp` property is an `NSTimeInterval`, so you should be able to do:

```
NSLog(@"Motion at time: %@",
[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:devicemotion.timestamp]);
```

`NSTimeInterval` is just a typedef'd `double` type, so you could use `%f` instead of `%@` and log it directly.

Also, the docs don't indicate whether this timestamp is set against Apple's reference date or the standard *nix date, so you may need to use `[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:]` if the aforementioned method returns dates far in the future.

As @davidbitton has suggested the `CMDeviceMotion`'s `timestamp` is relative to the last device boot, the correct `NSDate` could be derived by

```
NSDate *startupTime = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:
                          -1 * [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] systemUptime]];

NSDate *deviceMotionDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:devicemotion.timestamp 
                                              sinceDate:startupTime];
```

This should yield a roughly accurate `NSDate` object, assuming @davidbitton is correct. (reference: [NSProcessInfo -systemUptime](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSProcessInfo_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSProcessInfo/systemUptime))

However, given how complicated this is, I would now suggest for simplicity that, given the nature of the `timestamp` property, that you log it in a format string as something like

```
"... event logged at %0.2f seconds since startup...", devicemotion.timestamp
```

Comment: This doesn't work because the timestamp for a device motion sample is an NSTimeInterval from when the device was last booted. It is NOT from either of the common epochs of 1/1/2001 or 1970.

Comment: @davidbitton + flaggers + downvoter: updated with a (convoluted?) way to derive an `NSDate` given that the `CMDeviceMotion.timestamp` property is based on uptime.

Comment: This does not work either. -[NSProcessInfo systemUptime] will not give you the correct value while the CPU is asleep.

Comment: Wild. I don't think the CPU could be asleep when I wrote this. That's pretty cool.

Answer (score 11):

Here the solution I put in place because the date is according to Apple documentation :

> The time stamp is the amount of time in seconds since the phone booted.

I first save the originDate at the first mesure (if my NSDate is nil).

```
[self.motionManager startGyroUpdatesToQueue:self.queue withHandler:^(CMGyroData *gyroData, NSError *error) {
    if (self.originDate == nil) {
        self.originDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:-gyroData.timestamp];
    }   
}];
```

Then I can display when I want the real date like this :

```
[NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:mygyroData.timestamp sinceDate:self.originDate]
```

Don't forget to reset the originDate to nil if you need to restart some mesure.

Comment: After trying many variations of @ben-mosher's approach, I think this approach is best. It's a bit more of a pain to implement, but it doesn't rely on internal implementation details of -[NSProcessInfo systemUptime] and is thus a more defensive solution.