# In iOS, using Swift, how do you get the time of iPhone boot?

Tags: ios, swift

In core motion, data is returned in a class inheriting from `CMLogItem`, which has a `timestamp` property.  The `timestamp` is a `TimeInterval` that is the time since the device booted.

How do I get when the device booted?

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6911226/nslog-timestamp) has an answer by @gros with a good approach. The answer is in Objective-C, but it shouldn’t be too hard to convert; basically assume that the first update is delivered close enough to “now” that you can subtract the timestamp from “now” to get the boot time.

Comment: [`CACurrentMediaTime()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/1395996-cacurrentmediatime) returns the [`mach_absolute_time`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/kernel/1462446-mach_absolute_time), which is the time since reboot, and `CACurrentMediaTime` does the conversion to seconds for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the comments, I was able to find `ProcessInfo.processInfo.systemUptime` which is the time since last boot.  From this, and `Date()`, I can get the time of start via:

```
time_of_last_boot = Date() - ProcessInfo.processInfo.systemUptime
```

Comment: This is not correct. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23508656/1226963 and the comments below it. Then review the other answers.