# Get IPad on time, application on time for a xamarin native application

Tags: c#, xamarin, process, xamarin.ios

I am developing Xamarin.ios ipad application using c#. I need to get time when the device(ipad) switched on, time when my app started, the time when my app goes background etc. How can I get these values using Xamarin?

Thanks in Advance,
Roshil K

Comment: you can use app lifecycle events to capture timestamps of when your app starts, etc.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/backgrounding/application-lifecycle-demo

Comment: Yes. But I need to get  the time when the device first booted.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46415095/in-ios-using-swift-how-do-you-get-the-time-of-iphone-boot